# How to parse text messages on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt, qml, sms

Hi I want to be able to parse text messages on Ubuntu Touch for a specific key word.  I understand how to do it on Android, but it is looking like this is very different than on Ubuntu Touch.

Unfortunately I am unable to find any documentation for how to do this.  Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at the [Qt Mobility API](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility/index.html) specially the [Messaging API](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility/messaging.html) might be helpfull. Unfortunately there is no [offical core app](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/CoreApps) yet. So you may also contact the mailing list of the [Ubuntu Touch Launchpad project](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone). Because even though there is no offical app, you are able to send and receive sms and calls with the Ubuntu Touch Preview on Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4 (see the [Installation Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install)).